# Container и как с ним бороться

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, navigationbar

Добрый день уважаемые коллеги.

Возник такой вопрос, есть значит меню nav оно должно располагаться на всю ширину экрана, а после nav должен быть контейнер 1170px, но, нужно это сделать так, чтобы в nav был контейнер и до меня не доходит как это сделать.

Плюс еще надо выровнять список по центру вертикаль и горизонталь, и чтобы при наведении был тот эффект что сейчас есть, но только на всю высоту nav.

Единственные вещи которые меня тормозят это меню, оно должно быть фиксировано, чтобы всё было выровнено.

А так же ссылка 1 и 5 должны быть по разные стороны nav, прошу вас, помогите пожалуйста!

```css
* {
 margin: 0;padding: 0;
}

body {
 background: #272727;
 font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
}

nav {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #f9f9f9;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
}

a {
 padding: 20px;
 color: purple;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover {
 background: #272727;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как контейнер может быть после `nav` и внутри `nav` одновременно? Это 2 контейнера. И при чем тут вообще контейнер.

Comment: Есть контейнер 1170px, он располагается по центру, а есть nav, или может div который содержит этот контейнер.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы этот div / nav был на всю ширину экрана с каким-то цветом, а в нём контейнер который располагает элементы по его ширине, вот прям как на stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 7000px;
}

body {
    background: #272727;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
.menu{
    
position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.menu > ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
ul {
    position: absolute;

    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;

height: 100%;
    line-height: 100px;
 
}

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
height: 100%;
    color: purple;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover {
    background: #272727;
    color: red;
}
h2{
    
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
       <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h2>
  Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.

По своей сути рыбатекст является альтернативой традиционному lorem ipsum, который вызывает у некторых людей недоумение при попытках прочитать рыбу текст. В отличии от lorem ipsum, текст рыба на русском языке наполнит любой макет непонятным смыслом и придаст неповторимый колорит советских времен. 
    Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.

По своей сути рыбатекст является альтернативой традиционному lorem ipsum, который вызывает у некторых людей недоумение при попытках прочитать рыбу текст. В отличии от lorem ipsum, текст рыба на русском языке наполнит любой макет непонятным смыслом и придаст неповторимый колорит советских времен. 
    Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.

По своей сути рыбатекст является альтернативой традиционному lorem ipsum, который вызывает у некторых людей недоумение при попытках прочитать рыбу текст. В отличии от lorem ipsum, текст рыба на русском языке наполнит любой макет непонятным смыслом и придаст неповторимый колорит советских времен. 
    Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.

По своей сути рыбатекст является альтернативой традиционному lorem ipsum, который вызывает у некторых людей недоумение при попытках прочитать рыбу текст. В отличии от lorem ipsum, текст рыба на русском языке наполнит любой макет непонятным смыслом и придаст неповторимый колорит советских времен. 
  </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: На счет последнего пункта:1 и 5 ссылки должны обособленно от трех ссылок в центре стоять или же все меню должно растягиаться по длине nuv?

Comment: меню должно растягиваться по длине nav, но при этом
Нужно еще чтобы это меню было фиксированным

Comment: То есть при скроллинге не уезжало вверх?

Comment: Да, всё верно. 

У меня получается сделать фиксированым, но когда задают mt 100px для того блока что находится ниже чем это меню по разметке, у меня всё съезжает на 100px

Comment: Воть, все работает ;)

Comment: "Да, всё верно. У меня получается сделать фиксированым, но когда задают mt 100px для того блока что находится ниже чем это меню по разметке, у меня всё съезжает на 100px" надо добавить top:0 в fixed блоке